# Print without end seperator on last item

Tags: python

I need to print twin primes in the following manner

```
3:5,5:7,11:13,17:19
```

But my code is printing like this

```
3:5,5:7,11:13,17:19,
```

```
print("{0}: {1}" .format(n,n+2), end=', ')
```

I am using `end=','` in the print statement and hence the comma at the last.

Is there any other way of printing

Comment: Use `sep=','` instead

Comment: To use sep, the print() function has to have minimum two strings

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `end` make a string first via a join and print that

```
 print(", ".join(f"{n}:{n+2}" for n in my_list))
```

or you can print the entire list rather than iterating and printing and use `sep`

```
print(*(f"{n}:{n+2}" for n in my_list), sep=", ")
```